# Where can I find a West Sea form of Gastrodon?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I'm playing through Pokémon Sword and trying to fill up the pokédex. For completionist sake, I want to catch both forms of Gastrodon - The East Sea (blue/green) and The West Sea (pink/brown).

So far, I have encountered three locations where I can catch Shellos/Gastrodon, but I have only ever encountered the East Sea form.

Where can I find a West Sea form of Shellos/Gastrodon in Pokémon Sword? Are they version exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-swsh/gastrodon/), the West Sea form is **not** in the wild in these games and will only be available through Pokémon Home.

Comment: Given how Sword/Shield has been out for a month and half now and multiple reports state they are unable to find them, I can agree upon Serebii's claim that West Sea form can only be obtained through Pokemon Home (when it get's released)

Comment: @Wondercricket Commenting on a random port, because you have no contact information on your profile: Look how close we two were in the 2019 annual ranking: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/41/year/gaming You even overtook me multiple times for a few hours, so I got a lot more active than usual on this site in the last two weeks to squeeze out a few more points.

Comment: @FabianRöling Oh man, we were really close. Pretty much neck and neck towards the end, so congrats on being #1 for 2019! Also, you can always send me a message in chat :)

Answer (score -1):

They're not exclusive, you can find them in the wild area. Most notably between the different lakes they might have different forms for the Shellos/Gastrodon.

Comment: Are there any specific lakes I need to visit? Specific weather? Specific regions? I've been to various different lakes throughout the wild area, and only ever found east sea form. If you could add a screenshot of finding a east sea form or something of the sort, I would feel more inclined to accept this answer.

Comment: East sea is the blue one or the pink one ? I always forget. 
I usually see the blue one around lake Outrage, the pink one is more often near Axew's eye (the one where you get the spare apples)

Comment: The east sea is the blue one :) It's ok, I had to double check my question when I posted it to make sure I had the forms correct. I'm looking for the pink one. I'll check around Axew's Eye when get one tonight

Comment: So I've been searching around Axew's Eye the past coulpe of days, and still no pink Shellos/Gastordon

Comment: And still nothing.... Are you are thinking of the right Pokemon? You might be confused with [Jellicent](https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-swsh/jellicent/), which has a Blue and Pink gender variants

Comment: @Wondercricket I'm pretty sure it was a gastrodon and not a shellos, but sadly I can't find another one now. It might be link to days or maybe weather, i do not know.